# How to stop "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

How do I stop and start `setInterval`?

Suppose I have a `textarea`.  I want to stop `setInterval` on focus and restart `setInterval` on blur (with jQuery).

Comment: You have an example in:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483525/pausing-setinterval-when-page-browser-is-out-of-focus

Comment: It only takes one mouse click to accept an answer. It helps others too to see a correct answer amongst many answers. CLICK

Answer (score 191):

You have to store the *timer id* of the interval when you start it, you will use this value later to stop it, using the [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearInterval) function:

```
$(function () {
  var timerId = 0;

  $('textarea').focus(function () {
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      // interval function body
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('textarea').blur(function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

});
```

Comment: I would suggest to add a `if (timerId)clearInteral(timerId)` before `timerId = setInterval` - otherwise, it's not guaranteed that the interval is cleared if focus is called more often than blur. when testing this I saw this situation a few times (on IE10).

Comment: @PatrickKlug your right! I needed `if (timerId)clearInteral(timerId)` also

Answer (score 29):

This is based on CMS's answer. The question asked for the timer to be restarted on the blur and stopped on the focus, so I moved it around a little:

```
$(function () {
  var timerId = 0;

  $('textarea').focus(function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

  $('textarea').blur(function () {
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
     //some code here 
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Store the return of `setInterval` in a variable, and use it later to clear the interval.

```
var timer = null;
$("textarea").blur(function(){
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){ ... whatever ... }, 2000);
}).focus(function(){
    if(timer){
       window.clearInterval(timer);
       timer = null
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

setInterval returns an id that you can use to cancel the interval with clearInterval()

Comment: but how can i implement this with $.live or $.listen

Comment: `$.live` does not currently support `focus` and `blur` events.