# How can I stop "SetInterval"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to stop “setInterval”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831152/how-to-stop-setinterval)

How can I stop following setInterval function in to else condition

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#iframe1').is(':visible')) {

    } else {
         /// Here i want clear setInterval
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if($('#iframe1').is(':visible')) {

    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 200);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval

Answer (score 2):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) returns a handle which you can use in [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval):

```
var timerHandle = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#iframe1').is(':visible')) {

    } else {
        clearInterval(timerHandle);
    }
}, 200);
```

This also applies to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).