# how to stop “setInterval” when a load is inside it

Tags: jquery, load, setinterval

I have the same problem as there:
[how to stop "setInterval"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831152/how-to-stop-setinterval)

but when i have a load inside the setInterval it doesnt work,
this is what is inside test.php :

```
<div id="refresh">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>


<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  var timerId = 0;

  $('textarea').focus(function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

  $('textarea').blur(function () {
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
     $('#refresh').load('test.php #refresh');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `load` call destroys and recreates the `textarea`, and nothing attaches the event handlers to the new `textarea`. The handlers you're attaching only get attached to the original one, not the new replacement.

You can solve that with event delegation, since jQuery makes sure `blur` and `focus` bubble (even though they don't bubble natively on all browsers);

```
$(function () {
  var timerId = 0;

  $('#refresh').on('focus', 'textarea', function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

  $('#refresh').on('blur', 'textarea', function () {
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
     $('#refresh').load('test.php #refresh');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

That hooks the events on the `#refresh` element, but fires the handlers only if the event originated in a descendant `textarea` of it.

Or since there's no reason to be looking up `refresh` repeatedly:

```
$(function () {
  var timerId = 0,
      refresh = $("#refresh");

  refresh.on('focus', 'textarea', function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  });

  refresh.on('blur', 'textarea', function () {
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
     refresh.load('test.php #refresh');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Note that the change also means only `textarea` elements *within* the `#refresh` `div` get the events, whereas with your original code, *all* `textarea` elements on the page got it.